# Set iPhone date/time within app for testing purposes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have a lot of functionality in my app that is date/time dependent (e.g. "if date is x, show y).  I use [NSDate date] to get the current date/time of the user.  I can test functionality by manually changing the date/time on my iPhone but I'm wondering if there is a way to programatically overwrite the the current time so I can test in the simulator and more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create NSDate objects with any date/time you want.  Just run your code through a method to get "the current" time and inside this method either return the real date for production or some date of your choice for testing.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of doing it is to provide a custom implementation of +(NSDate *)date. You can swizzle this class method using [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle). Make a small category for the NSDate:

```
static NSTimeInterval seconds = 1300000000;

@interface NSDate (Fixed)
   + (NSDate *)fixedDate;
@end

@implementation NSDate (Fixed)
+ (NSDate *)fixedDate
{
  return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
}
@end
```

Then in the code where you want to have fixed date do the following:

```
NSError *error;
[NSDate jr_swizzleClassMethod:@selector(date) withClassMethod:@selector(fixedDate) error:&error];
NSLog(@"Date:%@", [NSDate date]);
```

The log prints out this:

```
2011-09-01 11:35:27.844 tests[36597:10403] Date:2011-03-13 07:06:40 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a category on `NSDate` and override `+[NSDate date]` method

```
+ (instancetype)date
{
  return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:100000]; // Replace with any date you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dateByAddingTimeInterval:

Returns a new NSDate object that is set to a given number of seconds relative to the receiver.

```
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

Parameters
seconds
The number of seconds to add to the receiver. Use a negative value for seconds to have the returned object specify a date before the receiver.
Return Value
A new NSDate object that is set to seconds seconds relative to the receiver. The date returned might have a representation different from the receiver’s.

source : the documentation :p

Comment: I don't think he wants a testing framework method but rather a system method to do a "roll forward" test on the entire app. It's like when you test a non-mobile app by setting the desktop unit's system time to something like 1/1/2040 to see if that breaks something.